# How can I make the google map only show main roads and building names, with dark background

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing my own navigation app based on google map api. How can I set the google map's layer to only show main roads and building names as typically observed in a navigation app like this

[image]

I have looked into diffremnt map type such as satalite, normal, hybrid, etc. None of these achieved the effect I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Map tiles are regulated by google so unless you make your own mapping tiles you cannot do what you want